# Azure Resource Management - OperationalInsights/workspaces - filter by tag broken?

Tags: c#, rest, azure, odata, azure-resource-manager

When querying the ARM API for Workspaces (with .NET SDK), I'm unable to provide TagName or TagValue filters.

I'm about to give the initial query a shot using the latest preview release of the v3.1+ ARM SDK. I'm unable to update the rest of my codebase to that package just yet because it's full of breaking changes.

**Update:** Despite the new 3.1+ ResourceManagementClient changing much of the SDK, it still send out the query using the same request with the same API version. (2014-04-01-preview)

**Update 2:** I expected this, but this issue is not limited to Workspaces, but any Provider/ResourceType combination.

---

**Problem:**

```
http://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resources?$filter=resourceType%20eq%20'Microsoft.OperationalInsights%2Fworkspaces'%20and%20tagvalue%20eq%20'{tagValue}'&api-version=2014-04-01-preview
```

> Error: InvalidFilterInQueryString
>
> Message: Invalid $filter 'resourceType eq 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces' and tagvalue eq '{tagValue}'' specified in the query string.

---

**Workaround:**
Query all workspaces and filter client-side

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resources?$filter=resourceType%20eq%20'Microsoft.OperationalInsights%2Fworkspaces'&api-version=2014-04-01-preview
```

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/{workspaceName}",
      "name": "{workspaceName}",
      "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces",
      "location": "{location}",
      "tags": { "Tag1": "TagValue1" }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**SDK:**

- Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources v2.18.11-preview
- Microsoft.Azure.Management.OperationalInsights v0.10.0-preview
- Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources v3.1.1-preview
- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory v3.6.212012344-alpha
- Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime v1.4.1
- Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure v2.1.0

---

**v2.18.11-preview:**

```
TokenCloudCredentials creds = await GetOldTokenCredentials(...);    
using (var armClient = new ResourceManagementClient(creds)
using (var opsClient = new OperationalInsightsManagementClient(creds))
{
    var workspaceQuery = new ResourceListParameters { ResourceType = "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces" };
    // invalid filter error
    // var workspaceQuery = new ResourceListParameters { ResourceType = "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces" , TagValue = "TagValue1" }; 
    var workspaces = await armClient.ListRecursiveAsync(workspaceQuery, null);

    if (workspaces.Any())
    {
        var resource = workspaces.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Tags.ContainsKey("TagName1") || x.Tags.Values.Contains("TagValue1"));
        var resourceGroup = MicrosoftResources.GetResourceGroupNameFromId(resource.Id);
        var workspaceResult = await opsClient.Workspaces.GetAsync(resourceGroup, resource.Name);
    }
}
```

---

**v3.1.1-preview:**

```
ServiceClientCredentials newCreds = await GetNewTokenCredentials();
armClient.SubscriptionId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
var workspaces = armClient.Resources.List(x => x.ResourceType == "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces");
// same as v2.18.11
```

---

**Auth + misc**

```
public class MicrosoftResources
{        
    public static string GetResourceId(string subscriptionId, string resourceGroup, string provider, string resourceName)
    {
        return $"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/{provider}/{resourceName}";
    }

    private readonly static string _rgStr = "resourceGroups/";
    private readonly static string _prStr = "/providers";
    public static string GetResourceGroupNameFromId(string id)
    {
        var rgStrIdx = (id.IndexOf(_rgStr) + _rgStr.Length);
        return id.Substring(rgStrIdx, id.IndexOf(_prStr) - rgStrIdx);
    }
}

async static Task<string> GetAuthToken(string tenantId, Guid clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/"+ tenantId);
    var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId.ToString(), clientSecret);
    var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential);

    if (authenticationResult == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
    }

    return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
}

// v2.18.11
async Task<TokenCloudCredentials> GetOldTokenCredentials(string tenantId, Guid clientId, string clientSecret, string subscriptionId)
{
    var token = await GetAuthToken(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    return new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, token);
}

// v3.1.1-preview
public static async Task<ServiceClientCredentials> GetNewTokenCredentials(string tenantId, Guid clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    var token = await GetAuthToken(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    return new TokenCredentials(token);
}
```

Comment: Almost two years later I have hit this problem where you can't create a resource query that filters on both resource type and tags. Looking at the documentation for [Find-AzureRmResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/find-azurermresource) there are two distinct option sets: One that allows you to filter using `-ResourceType` and another that allows you to filter using `-TagName` and `-TagValue` but not both at the same time. To me this indicates that this "bug" is by design and it is not possible to combine the filters.